# Find the missing character in a String palindrome

Tags: c, algorithm

The following is the code I had written to find the missing character in a string palindrome but I don't know how to find which character must be printed while checking the string from both the sides simultaneously.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[100], m[100];
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    int len = strlen(s);
    int a, b;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        m[i] = s[len - i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i <= strlen(s), j <= strlen(s); i++, j++) {
        if (isspace(m[j])) {
            j++;
        }
        if (s[i] != m[j]) {
            if (len % 2 == 0) {
                printf("%c", m[j]);
                break;
            } else {
                printf("%c", s[i]);
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Input: `Malayaam`
Output: `l`

Input: `abcddcb`
Output: `a`

Comment: `i<=strlen(s),j<=strlen(s)` does not do what you think it should.

Comment: Challenging test case "ZZxyxyxxyxyZZ" (remove left x) vs. "ZZxyxyyxyxyZZ" (remove right y).

Comment: @chux Nice one. But I think naming a letter to add is accepted solution for the question "Find the missing ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is always exactly one mistake in the palindrome, I recommend to look at the next letter on each side, for deciding which of two non-identical letters is the missing one.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[100],m[100];
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
    int len=strlen(s)-1;
    int i,j;


    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        m[i]=tolower((unsigned char)s[len-i-1]);
        s[i]=tolower((unsigned char)s[i]);
    }

    for(i=0,j=0;i<len;i++,j++)
    {
        if(s[i]!=m[j])
        {
            printf("%c != %c, ", s[i], m[j]);
            if(s[i+1]==m[j])
            { printf("but %c == %c, %c should be inserted on the right.\n", s[i+1], m[j], s[i]);
            } else if(s[i]==m[j+1])
            { printf("but %c == %c, %c should be inserted on the left.\n", s[i], m[j+1], m[j]);
            } else
            { printf("giving up.\n");
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- I incorporated the comments by mch and later chqrlie and chux
- I added a lowercasing of all input, to prevent "m"!="M" in "Malayaam"
- I think your [mcve] was not complete, so I edited a few things in.
- I edited a little for backward compatibility to older C
  (e.g. no declaration of `i` inside the for loop head).
- the assumption of exactly one mistake protects from some edge cases

Comment: Missing header `<ctype.h>`, should cast `char` argument to `tolower` and `isspace` as `tolower((unsigned char)s[i])`, `isspace((unsigned char)m[j])`...

Comment: Also `i<strlen(s)` -> `i < len` and `i<=strlen(s)` -> `i < len`.

Comment: @chqrlie True. Does not make a problem while exactly one mistake is in the palindrome, but surely better code that way. Thanks.

Comment: Was also wondering what for OP put that in. @chux Played with some spaces in the inpt, nothing was improved as far as I can tell. Removed.

Comment: @chux Getting late (here), my testing is shaky (must have forgotten to recompile ....). Thanks. I changed to simply skip the reliably present newline at the end.

Comment: `int len=strlen(s)-1;` is OK, but note that `s` does not always have a trailing `'\n'` and `s` could begin with a `'\0'`. Good enough for learner code though.

Comment: @chux I agree with "learners code", being in the safe kindergarden of a simple keyboard-typed-in string to work with, i.e. no funny '\0' and surely a newline. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Yunnosch That's about it.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce problems, by recognizing that input likely has a trailing `'\n'` that need not participate in the test.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char s[100];
  fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
  s[strcspn(s, "\r\n")] = '\0';
  size_t len = strlen(s);
```

When the string is not a palindrome due to 1 "extra" character, to remove the left or right character may not be discernible until a fair amount of processing of the remaining string.  Code needs to consider 2 paths.

```
  size_t mismatch;
  if (is_palindrome(s, len, &mismatch)) {
    puts("Palindrome");
  } else if (is_palindrome(s + mismatch + 1, len - mismatch*2 - 1, NULL)) { // skip left
    printf("left <%c>\n", s[mismatch]);
  } else if (is_palindrome(s + mismatch, len - mismatch*2 - 1, NULL)) { // skip right
    printf("right <%c>\n", s[len - mismatch-1]);
  } else {
    puts("Not palindrome nor off by 1 palindrome");
  }
}
```

All that is left is to make `is_palindrome()`

```
bool is_palindrome(const char *s, size_t len, size_t *mismatch) {
  printf("<%s> %zu\n", s, len);
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i + 1 < len) {
    if (tolower((unsigned char)s[i]) != //
        tolower((unsigned char )s[len - 1])) {
      if (mismatch) {
        *mismatch = i;
      }
      return false;
    }
    i++;
    len--;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
char s[100];
scanf("%[^\n]s",s);
int l=strlen(s);
for(i=0,j=l-1;i<l,j>=0;i++,j--)
{
     if(s[i]!=s[j])
     {
          if(s[i+1]==s[j])
          {
              printf("%c",s[i]);
              break;
          }
          else
          {
              printf("%c",s[j]);
              break;
          }
     }
}

/*find the missing letter in palindrome:
```

This code checks the first i and last character j of string and if it is equal then  i is incremented and j is decremented.if it is not equal it checks for the character next to i or j to be equal with the character, if i+1 is equal to j then i is missing and when j-1 is equal to i then j is the missing character in the string palindrome.*/

Comment: Please add more context to the answer explaining whats going on

Comment: @Mohmmad S okay tq i ll do the changes

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
char ar[102];
int ai=0;
int aj,ak;
scanf("%s",&ar);
ak = strlen(ar)-1;
ai = 0;
while(ai<ak){
    if(ar[ai]!=ar[ak]){
        if(ar[ai] == ar[ak-1] && ai!=ak-1){
            printf("%c",ar[ak]);
            break;
        }else{
            printf("%c",ar[ai]);
            break;
        }
    }
    ak--;
    ai++;
}
}
```